# Passing modal data in AngularJS using controller as and vm

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a pair of controllers that looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('room')
        .controller('RoomGetCtrl', Room)
        .controller('TestCtrl', Test)

    Room.$inject = [...'$uibModal'...];
    Test.$inject = [...'$uibModalInstance'...];

    function Room(..., $scope, $uibModal) {
        var vm = this;

        ... 

        vm.open = function (size) {

            vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                controller: 'TestCtrl as vm',
            });
        };
    }

    function Test(???){
        this.modalText = 'Modal Text'
        this.modalCancel = function() {
            ???.dismiss();
        }
    }
})();
```

The view looks like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Modal window</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <pre>{{ vm.modalText }}</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.modalCancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.open()">Open me!</button>
...
```

The above works, except that I'm unable to figure out what goes in the `???` in `Test()` above. I've tried a variety of things, whenever I click the cancel button, the console logs an error along the lines of "x.dismiss is not a function," where "x" is whatever I've tried use.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I instantaneously worked it out myself (I swear, posting the question makes me think better). Anyway, here:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('room')
        .controller('RoomGetCtrl', Room)
        .controller('TestCtrl', Test)

    Room.$inject = [...,'$uibModal'];
    Test.$inject = [$uibModalInstance];

    function Room(..., $uibModal) {
        /*jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;

        ...

        vm.open = function () {

            vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                controller: 'TestCtrl as vm',
            });
        };
    }

    function Test($uibModalInstance){
        this.modalText = 'Modal Text'
        this.modalCancel = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
        }
    }
})();
```

Really simple. `$uibModalInstance.dismiss();`. It was right there in the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started)

*sigh*